# Using aws ecs execute-command in aws not local for cron like usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have fargate container.

Now I can access the container and exec the command such as , (in this case I did `ls -la` for test)

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster tvn-prod-cn --container TravelDjangoContainer --interactive --command 'ls -la' --task 0e63831d80654bbb88cbcc4d002b3d4f
```

So, what  I would like to do is set this command as cron like.

My ideas are below

- set this command in `SSM RunCommand`
- trigger `RunCommand` by `EventBridge`

Is it possible ??

How can I set this command in RunCommand?

---

I made `lambda` with `serverless`

I googled around and make this script, but it's not correct,,, Could anyone helps or samples??

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const SSM = new AWS.SSM({region: 'ap-northeast-1'})
const REMOTE_WORKING_DIR = '/home/ec2-user'

module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
  try {
    let command = 'ls -la'

    let params = {
      DocumentName: 'AWS-RunExecScript',
      Parameters: {
        commands: [command],
        workingDirectory: [REMOTE_WORKING_DIR]
      },
      CloudWatchOutputConfig: {
        CloudWatchLogGroupName: 'SSMLogs',
        CloudWatchOutputEnabled: true
      },
      TimeoutSeconds: 3600 // 1 hour
    }

    SSM.sendCommand(params, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err, err.stack)
      } else {
        console.log(data)
      }
    });
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  };

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SSM RunCommand, which isn't really designed to run tasks in ECS, I would create a Lambda function that calls ECS [execute_command()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.execute_command) and schedule that using the [EventBridge cron schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html).

If you want to use SSM RunCommand, you would need an EC2 server that it could run the `aws ecs execute-command` CLI command from, which is surely not what you want.

Comment: Thank you I don't stick with the  RunCommand, so I made the lambda. I updated the article

Comment: You completely changed the content of your question. You should have just accepted my answer (since it is what you did) and then asked a new question about the Lambda function. Also, please don't post a bunch of code and just state "it's not correct". Include the actual error message or unexpected behavior in the question!

Comment: OK, thank you for your advice. I will research again and maybe make article. I made step forward thanks to you.

Comment: Note: you are still using SSM RunCommand in your code you posted, you are just calling it from Lambda. Instead you should be calling ECS execute command directly from Lambda, via the AWS SDK.